# Authenticate/Decrypt packet error: packet HMAC authentication failed

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

After updating OpenVPN 2.3.x. to OpenVPN 2.4.4 I have a problem for authentication all devices

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

**openvpnas.log**

```
2022-08-02T14:05:24+0200 [stdout#info] [OVPN 4] OUT: 'Tue Aug  2 12:05:24 2022 Authenticate/Decrypt packet error: packet HMAC authentication failed'
2022-08-02T14:05:24+0200 [stdout#info] [OVPN 4] OUT: 'Tue Aug  2 12:05:24 2022 TLS Error: incoming packet authentication failed from
```

**server.config**

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.200.0.0 255.255.254.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-config-dir ccd
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-CBC   # AES
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 4
```

**Client**

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote x.x.x.x 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert x.crt
key x.key
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth ta.key 1 
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
verb
```